# Accessing Google Family Link API

Tags: google-api

Hy,

I want to create a widget that show me some informations from Google Family Link.
But I can't find how to access to Google Family Link API.

I read this page of Google API list but didn't found it : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer?hl=fr

Can someone please show me where to find Google Family Link API doumentation please ?

Comment: I need this as well. I want to extend the functionality of family link. It would be great if they introduced an API for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no api for Google Family Link.   I wonder weather or not google would want third party developers creating apps for it.

The whole point of Google Family Link is to keep things secure and protected for children.

Comment: Presumably the API would prevent non-authorized users from changing settings but access to the API could help someone create a much better app than family link. It has several missing features. Better yet, they could release the API and support requests to improve the API.